# Mac Studio Display audio is choppy

Tags: mac, mac-studio

[I have one of the Mac Studio Displays with audio issues](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/08/02/studio-display-speaker-audio-issues/). The audio is choppy, cuts off, etc. Switching to alternative sound source works, but it's $1500 display and I expect it advertised six-speakers audio system to work.

Is there any permanent fix or any fix to this issue yet that would not involved shutting down your system overnight?

Comment: [More on the issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253801414).

Comment: Does the issue happen after a power cycle (or can you trigger  it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple released a firmware update (v15.5) that is supposed to fix the audio problems.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213110

Your Mac will reboot while the update is installed, but it's not 'overnight' -- it's a few minutes.

If you've already installed that, then I would take it back for a replacement unit. It's by no means a universal problem.